# Выделить лексические ошибки и указать тип каждой. Напишите свой вариант исправления.

Tags: языкознание

1. В связи с финансовым кризисом уровень жизни населения ухудшается.
2. Нашедшего документы на имя Тамары Брагиной прошу вернуть за вознаграждение.
3. В Калининграде отмечено подорожание цен на гречневую крупу.
4. Народ, ущемленный правами, живет сейчас очень бедно.
5. Коллеги его поздравляли и пели ему фимиам.
6. Учитель обязан содействовать исправлению допущенных родителями ошибок

Comment: @натка82, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

1. "Уровню" свойственно изменяться количественно, а не качественно.
2. Пропущено, "что" просят вернуть - грамматически такой оборот не исключает "возврата" человека, нашедшего документы (изловить его и вернуть - за вознаграждение).
3. Ошибка тавтологического свойства (подорожание = повышение цен -> "подорожание цен" = повышение цен на цены).
4. Ошибка в падеже слова "права" + с этим словом нужен предлог.
5. Объединены несовместимые части двух разных устойчивых выражений (фимиам не поют).
6. Глагол, применяемый, как правило, к людям (содействовать кому-то в чём-то) применён к процессу, а не к родителям.